# Create a google chart from XML data in a Symfony project

Tags: javascript, xml, symfony

Please I want to know where to put the XML file from where I retrieve data for the chart, in a Symfony project? 
I tried to put values directely in the javascript code and that worked, but when I retrieved data from XML to fill the chart, that didn't work and I got this error in the developer console : Failed to load resource

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      var drawChart= setInterval (function drawCharts() { 

      var xml=new XMLHttpRequest() ;
      xml.open("GET", "statFile.xml",true) ;//this is the line that causes the problem



    xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xml.readyState == 4) {
  var doc=xml.responseXML ;

  var root = doc.getElementsByTagName("CHART") ;

    ////VALUES IN
    var paramss= root[0].getElementsByTagName("VALUES_IN");
        console.log(paramss) ;
    var value_in1=paramss[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML;

    var value_in2=paramss[0].childNodes[3].innerHTML;

    var value_in3=paramss[0].childNodes[5].innerHTML;

    var value_in4=paramss[0].childNodes[7].innerHTML;

    var value_in5=paramss[0].childNodes[9].innerHTML;

    var value_in6=paramss[0].childNodes[11].innerHTML;

    var value_in7=paramss[0].childNodes[13].innerHTML;

    var value_in8=paramss[0].childNodes[15].innerHTML;

    var value_in9=paramss[0].childNodes[17].innerHTML;

    var value_in10=paramss[0].childNodes[19].innerHTML;

    var value_in11=paramss[0].childNodes[21].innerHTML;

    var value_in12=paramss[0].childNodes[23].innerHTML;

    ////VALUES OUT
    var paramsx= root3[0].getElementsByTagName("VALUES_OUT");
        console.log(paramsx) ;
    var value_out1=paramsx[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML;

    var value_out2=paramsx[0].childNodes[3].innerHTML;

    var value_out3=paramsx[0].childNodes[5].innerHTML;

    var value_out4=paramsx[0].childNodes[7].innerHTML;

    var value_out5=paramsx[0].childNodes[9].innerHTML;

    var value_out6=paramsx[0].childNodes[11].innerHTML;

    var value_out7=paramsx[0].childNodes[13].innerHTML;

    var value_out8=paramsx[0].childNodes[15].innerHTML;

    var value_out9=paramsx[0].childNodes[17].innerHTML;

    var value_out10=paramsx[0].childNodes[19].innerHTML;

    var value_out11=paramsx[0].childNodes[21].innerHTML;

    var value_out12=paramsx[0].childNodes[23].innerHTML;

    window.value_in1=value_in1;window.value_in2=value_in2;window.value_in3=value_in3;window.value_in4=value_in4;
    window.value_in5=value_in5;window.value_in6=value_in6;window.value_in7=value_in7;window.value_in8=value_in8;
    window.value_in9=value_in9;window.value_in10=value_in10;window.value_in11=value_in11;window.value_in12=value_in12;

    window.value_out1=value_out1;window.value_out2=value_out2;window.value_out3=value_out3;window.value_out4=value_out4;
    window.value_out5=value_out5;window.value_out6=value_out6;window.value_out7=value_out7;window.value_out8=value_out8;
    window.value_out9=value_out9;window.value_out10=value_out10;window.value_out11=value_out11;window.value_out12=value_out12;


         drawChart();

         function drawChart(){
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Mois', 'Frequence'],
          [value_in1,  parseInt(value_out1)],
          [value_in2,  parseInt(value_out2)],
          [value_in3,  parseInt(value_out3)],
          [value_in4,  parseInt(value_out4)],
          [value_in5,  parseInt(value_out5)],
          [value_in6,  parseInt(value_out6)],
          [value_in7,  parseInt(value_out7)],
          [value_in8,  parseInt(value_out8)],
          [value_in9,  parseInt(value_out9)],
          [value_in10,  parseInt(value_out10)],
          [value_in11,  parseInt(value_out11)],
          [value_in12,  parseInt(value_out12)],

        ]);
        /*series: {
          2 : { areaOpacity: 10 },
         };
         */

        var options = {
          title: 'Fréquence des visites du site',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' },
          backgroundColor: {
          fill : 'transparent'
          }

        };



        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
         }

 } }
  xml.send() ;
  });   
        },30000);
```

Comment: yes I worked on a dashboard project before, and I used the same code, it works outside symfony framework in any normal project, but I'm new in symfony and this is the first time I use xml in a symfony project

Comment: And when I open the console I see many errors like : Failed to load resource

Comment: I just want to know where to put my xml file and how to put its location in : xml.open("GET", "statFile.xml",true) ;

Comment: Yes I put it in the views folder

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)"

Comment: that means the xml file is not loaded

Comment: Sooo please how can I solve this problem?! the statFile.xml is in the views Folder I'm sure :(

Comment: I don't understand what the views folder is in relation to the page that has this code in it - I don't know symfony at all, so I'm going to remove all my comments because I can not help at all

Comment: may I suggest you "remove" the code inside the `if (xml.readyState == 4) {` block to make your question more readable - at least now the code in the question looks like you're using XMLHttpRequest correctly, which confused me before you edited the code

Comment: Is there any guru in symfony to help me? :( I'm stack